# Ошибка error C2039: Path_Head: не является членом "Lst_Paths"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, шаблоны-с++

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь заполнить список списков, но вылезает ошибка.
Имеются 2 списка:

```
struct Lst_Paths
{
    char *ID;
    Lst_Paths *Next;
    Lst_Paths *Prev;
};
struct Lst_Taxi
{
    char *ID;
    Lst_Paths *Path_Head;
    Lst_Taxi *Next;
    Lst_Taxi *Prev;
};
```

И есть функция их заполнения:

```
template <class Type>
Type *Insert(Type *Head, char *ID, bool bval)
{
    Type *tmp = NULL;
    Type *Prev_to_Next = NULL;
    char *PATH_ID;
    char choice = 'N';
    if (Head == NULL)
    {
        Head = new Type;
        Head->ID = new char;
        Head->ID = ID;
        Head->Prev = Head->Next = NULL;
        Prev_to_Next = Head;
        tmp = Head;
    }
    else
    {
        tmp = Head;
        while (tmp)
        {
            Prev_to_Next = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->Next;
        }
        tmp = new Type;
    tmp->ID = new char;
    tmp->ID = ID;
    Prev_to_Next->Next = tmp;
    Prev_to_Next = tmp;
    tmp->Next = NULL;
}
if (bval)
{
    tmp->Path_Head = NULL;
    cout << "Let's set path of texi with ID: " << tmp->ID;
    do
    {
        cout << "Type path ID.\nFor example: A\n";
        PATH_ID = new char;
        cin >> PATH_ID;
        tmp->Path_Head = Insert<Lst_Paths>(tmp->Path_Head, ID, false);
        cout << "Press Y or y to exit, otherwise press random button to continue.\n";
        cin >> choice;
    } while (toupper(choice) != 'Y');
}
tmp = NULL;
Prev_to_Next = NULL;
return Head;
}
```

Сама ошибка в этой строке:

```
tmp->Path_Head = Insert<Lst_Paths>(tmp->Path_Head, ID, false);

error C2039: Path_Head: не является членом "Lst_Paths"
```

Я подумал, что ошибка когда у же при повторном вызове функции я пытаюсь обратится к

```
Path_Head
```

но tmp уже не имеет тип

```
Lst_Paths
```

для этого я ввел булевскую переменную, которая предотвращает вход в эту функцию 3 раз. Но ошибка осталась, уже не знаю что и делать. Пожалуйста не предлагайте списки STL.

Comment: Глядя на

    tmp->ID = new char;
    tmp->ID = ID;

предвижу ещё множество проблем.

Answer (score 3):

Вы не совсем хорошо понимаете, как работают шаблоны в C++.

Шаблон — конструкция времени компиляции. Шаблонная функция компилируется целиком, а не построчно во время выполнения.

Если вы пишете `Insert<Lst_Paths>`, то компилируется **вся** функция `Insert` с шаблонным параметром `Type = Lst_Paths`. При этом вызов `tmp->Path_Head` компилируется тоже как часть этой функции, и компилятору глубоко пофиг, что эта строчка не будет выполнена в силу вашей программной логики.

Если вы хотите, чтобы инстанциации шаблоны для разных типов вели себя по-разному, вам придётся выучить шаблоны посерьёзнее. Копайте в сторону partial template specialization.

Мне кажется, однако, что для вашей задачи нет смысла делать всё так сложно. Вы можете просто попробовать разбить функцию на две.

Comment: Здравствуйте, я понимаю, но просто тогда получатся 2 большие функции, которые делают одно и тоже, просто для разных структур.
Я все же не понимаю, когда я вызываю Insert<Lst_Paths>, то и аргументы такие Insert(Lst_Paths, ID, BOOL), почему так не работает? Я ведь и хочу что бы они работали одинаково, но для разных типов.
И что не так с 

    tmp->ID = new char;
    tmp->ID = ID;

Спасибо, за ответы.

Comment: @Саша Калюжный: Вы не так поняли. Вам надо не скопипастить одну функцию два раза, а разделить (разрезать, отщипнуть, придумайте сами синоним) её на две функции. Вы же и так пытаетесь различить два случая при помощи параметра `bval`.

---
Судя по всему, вы не знаете, как работают C-шные строки. [Я бы предложил перейти на `std::string` (и на STL, да).] Какова цель строки

    tmp->ID = new char;

?

Comment: Как я понимаю, я выделяю память под char, разве нет?
Насчет bval, эта булевская для того что бы не выполнять функцию внутри 2 раза, т.е. создаю один элемент структуры lst_taxi а в этом элементе несколько элементов lst_paths, но когда создаю элемент lst_paths, внутри этого элемента мне не нужно создавать другие элементы, для этого и есть моя булевская переменная, а так то по сути для создания элементов lst_taxi и lst_paths используются одинаковые средства.

Comment: @Саша Калюжный: Отлично, выделяете память. А _сколько_ этой самой памяти вы выделяете? И что вы делаете с выделенной памятью в следующей строке? Что, по вашему, делает оператор присваивания?

Я понимаю, зачем вы планировали использовать `bval`. Но всё же, почему вы не хотите из одной функции, которая иногда ещё делает дополнительную работу, сделать две функции? Вынесите дополнительную работу в отдельную функцию.